# how to solve this debugging problem in VS Code?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I opened flutter in VS Code. However, when I tried to run the basic code on main page it gave me this error, and it didn't run on the emulator
[image]

Comment: It would be a good idea to share your complete code, and please [avoid uploading code as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: it is the basic code that shows first after opening flutter. I didnt write any thing, and that is the problem